# CSS - Display flat list of divs in groups of 8

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'd like to display grid of numbers in groups of 8. For example - lets say we have a 32 divs - each one with a number:

```
1  9   17  25
2  10  18  26
3  11  19  27
4  12  20  28
5  13  21  29
6  14  22  30
7  15  23  31
8  16  24  32
```

What I am struggling with, is making it wrap to next line when there is not enough width. If there is not enough width, I'd like it to look like this:

```
1  9   17
2  10  18
3  11  19
4  12  20
5  13  21
6  14  22
7  15  23
8  16  24

25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
```

I am trying to use css grid, however I can't make it wrap to next line, when needed. Number of divs will always be repetition of 8.

My css class for grid:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6grct3no/

Comment: CSS-Grid does not wrap like that. You would have to parse them out in groups of 24 into separate containers with `display:grid`.

Comment: I could, however it is not guaranteed that parsing it into groups of 24 is enough - It may need to be grouped into groups of 16, or 8 if screen is too narrow.

Comment: You are trying to do this statically or dynamically

Comment: Dynamically - the only thing that is sure, is that number of divs will be repetition of 8. It can be 8, 16, 32...

Comment: Hi do u want this to be in any ways or using grid only you want this approach

Comment: It doesnt have to use grids :)